# Do all smooth extensions of a smooth function $f(x,y)$ defined on $\mathbb{H}^2$ have the same partial derivatives at $(a,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let us settle the symbol $\mathbb{H}^2$ first. By this, we mean the closed upper half-plane $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\geq 0\}$. Then, suppose we are given a smooth real-valued function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{H}^2$ that admits two smooth extensions $\tilde{f},\hat{f}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Here we use the term "smooth" to mean a function has continuous partial derivatives of all orders. Now pick any point on the $x$-axis, like $(a,0)$. What can we infer about the first-order partial derivatives of $\tilde{f},\hat{f}$? Let me go straight. Can we conclude that
$$\frac{\partial\tilde{f}}{\partial x}(a,0)=\frac{\partial\hat{f}}{\partial x}(a,0)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\frac{\partial\tilde{f}}{\partial y}(a,0)=\frac{\partial\hat{f}}{\partial y}(a,0)?$$
I think the answer is confirmative and has something to do with $C^1$, but I don't know how to write down an explicit proof. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: My argument is that $\tilde{f}$ and $\hat{f}$ agree on $\mathbb{H}^2$ and have continuous first-order partial derivatives.

Comment: What is the definition of "smooth on $\mathbb H^2?$

Comment: A function $f$ defined on an arbitrary (not necessarily open) subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is said to be smooth if at each point $p$ of $A$, $f$ admits a smooth extension $\tilde{f}$ to a neighborhood $U_p$ (may not contain the whole $A$) of $p$, that is, $\tilde{f}$ is smooth in the ordinary sense and $\tilde{f}=f$ on $U_p\cap A$.

Comment: So the hypothesis is we have $\tilde f,\hat f,$ smooth on $\mathbb R^2,$ that agree on $\mathbb H^2?$ And smooth = $C^1?$

Comment: Not quite. By "smooth", I mean $C^\infty$. What I am saying here is that $C^1$ will serve the purpose.